# Toggle element on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, fuelux

I'm using [Fuelux Checkbox](http://getfuelux.com/javascript.html#checkbox) component and I'm trying to toggle some DIV based on checkbox checked. I'm doing as follow:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#chkSucursal').on('checked.fu.checkbox', function (evt, item) {
        $("#rifEmpresa").toggle(!this.checked);
        $("#rifSucursal").toggle(this.checked);
    });

    $('#chkRif').on('checked.fu.checkbox', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").toggle(!this.checked);
    });
});
```

But is not working since `#rifEmpresa` is always show no matter what checkbox is checked or not. Te right way should be:

1. Check the first visible checkbox "Click me"
2. Hide `#rifEmpresa` DIV and show `#rifSucursal` right now that is show but the first is not hide
3. Toggle `#rifEmpresa` on **RIF?** checkbox checked

This is the related HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="registroEmpresa" role="form" class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div id="chkSucursal" data-initialize="checkbox" class="checkbox highlight">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 control-label"><strong>Check me</strong>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 checkbox">
                        <label class="checkbox-custom">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="sucursal" name="sucursal" value="1" class="sr-only">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="display: none;" id="rifSucursal" class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Find company<span class="text-danger">(*)</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">Some FORM element to Show</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="chkRif" data-initialize="checkbox" class="checkbox highlight">
                        <div class="col-xs-4 control-label"><strong>RIF?</strong>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4 checkbox">
                            <label class="checkbox-custom">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chkRif" name="chkRif" value="1" class="sr-only"> <span class="checkbox-label">(check me to show "Some Form Element to HIDE")</span>

                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="rifEmpresa" class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label class="col-xs-4 control-label">RIF <span class="text-danger">(*)</span>
                </label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">Some FORM element to Hide</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can any give me some help and tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix my code? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/31roa5hz/1/) is a simple Fiddle for testing purposes

Comment: Try `#rifEmpresa:checked` ...

Comment: it is because `this` inside the event handler is not the checkbox element

Comment: In the place of `this.checked`, try ... `$(***).is(":checked")` ... *** should be the "checkbox element"

Comment: @ArunPJohny so? I need to relies on `.show()/.hide()`?

Comment: @rfornal I've updated the code in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/31roa5hz/3/) and is not working, can you take a look?

Comment: @ReynierPM it won't work that way as the control ID you're using is not the actual id of your checkbox. it's the Div id not the checkbox id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/31roa5hz/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html').addClass('fuelux');

    $('#chkSucursal').on('checked.fu.checkbox', function (evt, item) {
        $("#rifEmpresa").hide('slow');
        $("#rifSucursal").show('slow');
    });


    $('#chkSucursal').on('unchecked.fu.checkbox', function (evt, item) {
        $("#rifEmpresa").show('slow');
        $("#rifSucursal").hide('slow');
    });


    $('#chkRif').on('checked.fu.checkbox', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").show('slow');
    });

        $('#chkRif').on('unchecked.fu.checkbox', function () {
        $("#rifEmpresa").hide('slow');
    });

});
```

I think the control you're using doesn't have any property as checked, i tried to know if that element is checked or not using .is(':checked') it returns undefined. so i think the updated code is better for you as the UI control you're using has its own custom events which can be captured.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

`$('input').on('change', checkboxChanged);`

Like a normal checkbox. If you can't, it's a bug and you may want to try checking out/bower install #master, since we have been bugfixing the checkbox control [over the past two weeks](https://github.com/ExactTarget/fuelux/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+milestone%3A3.5.0).

I do know that the `checked` attribute was not getting set in Fuel UX 3.4.0.